# No datetime module in python how to install via easy_install?

Tags: python, datetime, easy-install, python-module, python-datetime

I can find the module https://pypi.python.org/pypi/DateTime

But I don't know the command to install via easy_install. I'm getting a `no module named datetime` error and so I need to get this installed.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to install Zope's `DateTime` module? The code is rather... outdated and archaic. Outside of a Zope or Plone project, I can't see much use for it.

Comment: I'm using a python application with lots of community modules. One of the modules I want has the dependency on DateTime.

Comment: @o_O: Are you sure? Because the error message you posted is complaining about `datetime`, not `DateTime`.

Comment: Yeah I just wrote it from memory and not a copy paste. Following the answers below set me straight and fixed my errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Module names are case sensitive. `easy_install DateTime` works for me:

[image]

Comment: +1 You both are geniuses. If I could get half of that I think I'd be alright.

Answer (score 5):

The package, like the module, is named `DateTime`, not `datetime`. `datetime` is a different module, which is already [part of Python's standard library](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html).

When I do this, it works:

```
$ sudo easy_install-2.7 DateTime
```

---

Because `easy_install` is a big collection of PyPI-scraping hacks designed to make your life easier rather than an interface to a well-defined API, *sometimes* you can get away with getting the case wrong, or even leaving bits off, and it'll figure out what you mean and install the right thing. But you should not rely on this, because sometimes you *can't* get away with it.

Of course you really should be using `pip` instead of `easy_install`.

And you probably shouldn't be using this module at all. Notice that it says right at the top "Unless you need to communicate with Zope 2 APIs, you're probably better off using Python's built-in datetime module". And the fact that your error is `no module named datetime` implies pretty strongly that your code is trying to use `datetime`, not `DateTime`, so installing this won't help you.

Comment: +1 You both are geniuses. If I could get half of that I think I'd be alright.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Mac:

In order to install the **DateTime** library you have to install 'pip' first (see **Official instructions** on [How to install pip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12476379/3057986))

Then you can install DateTime library running this command on Terminal:

```
pip install DateTime
```

Hope it helps.